# Why I can't list all queries via GraphiQl introspection query?

Tags: graphql

I am learning GraphiQl now and try to list all available queries that I can make. I run this:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and eventually get some schema types, but not all of them. If I look up docs that are on the right side ("Documentation explorer") I can see root types `query: Query` that lists more queries like `user` and `users` (these were not shown on my introspection queries). There are few screenshots:
[image: ss1]
[image: ss2[![ss3]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQQ9H.png)

Question: how could I view these lowerCase methods like `allUsers` from query?  For example, I won't have access to docs and will have only introspection query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the query that you're using as shown, it would only give you the **Types** of objects. You can get all the queries of `Query` type with the below:

```
{
  __schema {
    queryType {
      name
      fields {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example, running the above on GitHub's GraphQL responds with the below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "queryType": {
        "name": "Query",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "codeOfConduct"
          },
          {
            "name": "codesOfConduct"
          },
          {
            "name": "enterprise"
          },
          {
            "name": "enterpriseAdministratorInvitation"
          },
          {
            "name": "enterpriseAdministratorInvitationByToken"
          },
          {
            "name": "license"
          },
          {
            "name": "licenses"
          },
          {
            "name": "marketplaceCategories"
          },
          {
            "name": "marketplaceCategory"
          },
          {
            "name": "marketplaceListing"
          },
          {
            "name": "marketplaceListings"
          },
          {
            "name": "meta"
          },
          {
            "name": "node"
          },
          {
            "name": "nodes"
          },
          {
            "name": "organization"
          },
          {
            "name": "rateLimit"
          },
          {
            "name": "relay"
          },
          {
            "name": "repository"
          },
          {
            "name": "repositoryOwner"
          },
          {
            "name": "resource"
          },
          {
            "name": "search"
          },
          {
            "name": "securityAdvisories"
          },
          {
            "name": "securityAdvisory"
          },
          {
            "name": "securityVulnerabilities"
          },
          {
            "name": "topic"
          },
          {
            "name": "user"
          },
          {
            "name": "viewer"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can search for the remaining fields within `fields` that you might need to add to your query by searching for `__Field` in the Documentation Explorer of GraphiQL.

[image]